# Login to asp.net site from another app, then receive filestream

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, wget

I have an ASP.NET application with pages that use reportviewer.  Can someone give me a hint on how to approach the following requirement:

**I want to get the report as PDF file from the page, without user interaction. I know I can render the report to a filestream, but since there's no user opening it in a browser, I need to collect the filestream from another application that might run during the night.**

There might be other approaches, like a webservice for example that could return the filestream to me, but this would also mean, I have to modify the setup of the datasources that the report receives it's data from. There are a lot of controls on the page, for supplying filter parameters. By using the page life cycle I can use what's already there.

I thought about wget, but haven't tried it yet, and I'm not sure how complicated logging in will be with cookies. I do have full control over the asp.net application though, so if I can modify something there to make it easier, I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "WebClient" in .net application to get the response from the site.

Please refer the below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx